# Using a variable that has been defined inside render, to use it inside return

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-hooks

so I'm getting certain redmax and redmin values through props and I've stored them in a variable. The below code is inside render. This is how it looks:

```
if(props.gauge.id === 8){
    let redMaxPressure = (props.gauge.params.red_max).split(',').map(function(i){
        return parseInt(i,10)
    })
    let redMinPressure = (props.gauge.params.red_min).split(',').map(function(i){
        return parseInt(i,10)
    })
    console.log('RedMax',redMaxPressure)
}
```

Now, I want to use those values inside the 'rect' svg but I'm unable to use that as it's throwing an error.

```
<rect
            x={-0.305}
            y={0.63}
            rx={0.02}
            width={0.6}
            height={0.3}
            fill={props.size !== 'small' && props.value <= redMaxPressure[0] ? rectColor : props.size === 'small' && props.value >=redMaxPressure[1] ? rectColor : '#ffffff00' }
            stroke={'black'}
            stroke-width={0.02}
            />
```

I'm getting an error for redMaxPressure[0] and redMaxPressure[1]. Is there a different way to use those values stored?

Note: The rect svg is inside return.

Answer (score 1):

Your `redMaxPressure`, `redMinPressure` are not in scope of `rect` element, because currently they live (variables lifetime) only in `if` scope, so their values are `undefined`.

You should ensure they in scope:

```
let redMaxPressure = DEFAULT_MAX;
let redMinPressure = DEFAULT_MIN;
if(props.gauge.id === 8){
    redMaxPressure = ...
    redMinPressure = ...
}

return <rect fill={props.size !== 'small' && props.value <= redMaxPressure[0] ? rectColor : props.size === 'small' && props.value >=redMaxPressure[1] ? rectColor : '#ffffff00' } />
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error now, but it's not picking the value. I set the default to an empty array. I want the rectangular to box to blink but it's not doing that. When I hard code the value, it does but when I use redMaxPressure[0] it doesn't.

Comment: No one can guess what your code does, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So basically there is a pressure and temperature gauge and the value of those gauges is given inside a rectangular svg. I want the rectangle box to repeatedly blink, if the value is below a given range. That's what the condition in fill does. Also, I tried using redMaxTemperature as a condition and it works fine, but for some reason redMaxPressure not being picked up. Maybe because it's an array. Let me know if you want more code/context. Haven't shared the code related to blinking since it works fine as I mentioned when we hard code values.

Comment: If you want this problem solved provide **reproducible example** your value may have closures (google it), it won't help without seeing actual **working code** as explained in the link I shared. Provide full code with codesandbox as expected from stackoverflow questions

Comment: I don't know how to use CodeSandBox for complex code. There is multiple interlinking of files. In fact, I've never used it before. Maybe, I'll just have to ask the senior Dev.

Comment: Also, when I debug, I observe is that the value for pressure comes initially and then the value of temperature comes in. When the value of temperature comes in, since we have already set the pressure as empty array, the initial values get replaced by empty values due to re-rendering. I want to somehow keep the value of pressure even when value of temp comes during re-rendering. As you can see, both don't come at same time.